# How to find the percentage of NAs in a data.frame?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, na

I am trying to find the percentage of NAs in columns as well as inside the whole dataframe:

The first method which I have commented gives me zero and the second method which is not commented gives me a matrix. Not sure what I am missing. Any hint is truly appreciated!

```
cp.2006<-read.csv(file="cp2006.csv",head=TRUE)

#countNAs <- function(x) { 
#  sum(is.na(x)) 
#} 
#total=0
#for (i in col(cp.2006)) {
#  total=countNAs(i)+total
#}
#print(total)
count<-apply(cp.2006, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
dims<-dim(cp.2006)
num<-dims[1]*dims[2]
NApercentage<-(count/num) * 100
print(NApercentage)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
x = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, NA, 3), y = c(NA, NA, 4, 5))
```

For the whole dataframe:

```
sum(is.na(x))/prod(dim(x))
```

Or

```
mean(is.na(x))
```

For columns:

```
apply(x, 2, function(col)sum(is.na(col))/length(col))
```

Or

```
colMeans(is.na(x))
```

Comment: I was just working with is.na(X) and realized I don't even need apply, right? `> sum(is.na(cp.2006))
[1] 138`

Comment: or just `mean(is.na(x))`

Comment: `cols.NA<apply(cp.2006,2,function(col)sum(is.na(col))/length(col))*100`

Comment: @fernando why the second argument to your `apply` function is `2` ?

Comment: I noticed you edited to `prod(dim(x))` after I posted my answer.  Nice.

Comment: Or df.isna().mean()

Answer (score 8):

Updated version of dplyr which doesnt support funs anymore:

`x%>% summarise_all(list(name = ~sum(is.na(.))/length(.)))`

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `dplyr::summarize_all` for the column-wise proportions.

```
x %>% summarize_all(funs(sum(is.na(.)) / length(.)))
```

Which will give

```
     x   y
1 0.25 0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested to find percentage of complete cases.

Using Same Example [mentioned here.](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html)

```
x = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, NA, 3), y = c(NA, NA, 4, 5))
```

Output :

```
   x  y
1  1 NA
2  2 NA
3 NA  4
4  3  5
```

Finding Complete cases:

```
complete.cases(x)
```

Output :

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Percentage of complete cases:

```
mean(complete.cases(x))
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.25
```

That means 25% of complete rows are available in data provided. i.e Only fourth row is complete rest all contains NA values.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This

```
colMeans(is.na.data.frame(dataframe_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```r
sapply(data, function(y) round((sum(length(which(is.na(y))))/nrow(data))*100.00,2))
```